# Вывод из функции

Tags: консоль, c++, функции

Есть функция `main()`, которая вызывает ф-ию `addcat()`. В ф-ии `addcat()` должен осуществляться вывод `printf("sud")`. Но этого не происходит. Почему?

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define enter printf("\n");

    struct account{
        char * login;
        char * pass;
        char * name;
    };

    struct categories{
        account * accs;
        char    * name;
    };

    categories * cats=0; 
    categories * pcat; 
    account    * pacc;

    int addcat(){ 
        return 12;
        printf("%s","ikiki");
    };

    void main(){

    printf("addcat, addacc");  enter;
    char cin[255]; 
    retry: 
    scanf("%s", &cin);

    if (strcmp(cin, "addcat")==0) addcat();
    printf("%d", addcat() );

    goto retry;

    enter; system("pause");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вроде этот код работает как у вас написано и все выводит.

```
#include <cstdio>

void addcat()
{
    printf("sud");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    addcat();
    return 0;
}
```

У вас ошибка в функции addcat.
Вы оператором return выходите с функции с возвращением числа 12.  
Так как после оператора return функция прекращает свою работу, поэтому до printf() просто не доходит дело.

Сделайте функцию такой...

```
int addcat()
{ 
    printf("%s","ikiki");
    return 12;   
}
```

Comment: @Roman Goriachevskiy, ща код дам

Comment: @Roman Goriachevskiy, вот я идиот). Благодарю.